# PostgREST - Add authenticated user id on insert

Tags: postgresql, supabase, postgrest, supabase-database

I need to automatically add an author of an inserted row in one of its columns. I am using postgREST (using Supabase cloud service) and I don't want users to add whoever they want as the author. Is there a way to automatically add user id of the user posting the data? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The column's **DEFAULT** value should be:

1. **uid()** for Supabase.
2. **current_user** for Postgres.

Answer (score 7):

You can add it via Table Editor or use `auth.uid()` in your SQL functions.

[image: Admin Panel]